GitHub Pages 404 error despite successful deployment
I'm having an issue with deploying my GitHub Pages site. Despite successfully deploying my project using GitHub Actions, my Pages site is showing a 404 error at the URL:
https://joelbyrd.github.io/job-listings/
Here are the details of my setup:

Repository Details:

Repository URL: https://github.com/joelbyrd/job-listings
Repository Name: job-listings
Repository Visibility: Public
Pages Source: Set to GitHub Actions


What I’ve Verified:

The gh-pages branch contains the following files:

index.html is in the root directory.
CSS and JS files are in the assets/ folder (e.g., /assets/style.css, /assets/app.js).


My vite.config.ts file has the correct base setting:
base: '/job-listings/',


The GitHub Actions workflow completes successfully, and files are pushed to the gh-pages branch.


Actions Taken to Troubleshoot:

Cleared my browser cache and tested the URL in multiple browsers.
Waited more than an hour (days) to account for propagation delays.
Verified that the Pages settings in Settings > Pages are correctly configured for GitHub Actions.
Tried manually toggling the Pages source setting to refresh it (set it to None, then back to GitHub Actions).
Checked the contents of the gh-pages branch and verified the expected files are there (the contents of the dist folder).


Issue Observed:

The Pages settings do not display the expected site URL (https://joelbyrd.github.io/job-listings/).
Accessing the URL results in a 404 error.



Why isn't anything being published to the GitHub Pages site? Are there any additional settings or configurations I need to adjust?

What does your configuration look like under Settings -> Code and automation -> Pages?

@Phil - there are only a couple configs there - under Build and Deployment, Source is set to Github Actions....Custom Domain is blank (uses the default joelbyrd.github.io domain), and Enforce HTTPS is checked.

I know your issue. In the following image is the configuration needed to host your site.

You have it on Github Actions. That only works with certain types of workflows. You said your Github Actions directs built files to gh-pages branch. So that means all your websites files are in the gh-pages branch, we can just select "Deploy from a branch". Put the branch as gh-pages like in the image, click save and wait for it to republish and that should fix it!

Another option if you don't like deploying from another branch (gh-pages)
This will update the server files everytime you push to the main branch. It will run npm run build and upload files in dist without creating or updating the gh-pages branch
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Build project
        run: npm run build

      - name: Setup Pages
        id: pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v3

      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: github-pages
          path: ./dist

  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build-and-deploy
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v2


